# GetListItems returns no items when filtering by lookup columns

Tags: web-services, caml-query

I am using the SP `Lists` service, the `GetListItems` method as follows (`guidView` is set to the "All Items" view):

```
listasSoap.getListItems(
  guidList,
  guidView,
  null,
  viewFields,
  "0",
  null,
  "");
```

And getting back all 22069 items.

Now, I retrieve the contents of the `ows_Contrato` field of one of those items, who happens to be, for example:

```
667;#ABAP14
```

And try the following queries:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Contrato"/><Value Type="Lookup">667;#ABAP14</Value></Eq></Where></Query>

<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Contrato" LookupId="True"/><Value Type="Lookup">667</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

But those queries return 0 items (despite the values being copy pasted from the `ows_Contrato` field.

I am generating the query Strings and SOAP object programmatically, and they work as they should for other lists. Yet no matter how many times I try, I cannot retrieve any items (0 elements with "z:row" tag name).

OTOH, a `where` directly to the ID works as expected.

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Counter">23984</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

What could be the issue that I am facing? As I said, other lists of the site work perfectly with similar queries.

The client is Java, the server is SharePoint 2007.

Comment: try to use the internal name of the field into the CAML query and maybe try your query with a CAML query simulator

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two errors:

- Looking up "by value" (without the `LookupId="True"` attribute) needs me to pass **only** the value of the field referenced/show; in other words the value right of the `;#`:

  ```
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Contrato"/>
        <Value Type="Lookup">ABAP14</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  ```

  Anyway this error is kind of secundary to me, since I usually use search by ID (safer in case the value is repeated, and more straight-forward); I tried it out of the issues with the search by ID
- The issues of looking up "by ID" seems related to [the fact that the list is indexed by that field](http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/05/why-should-indexing-a-sharepoint-field-break-your-caml-query/). The solution for these situation is changing the type of the value to `Integer`; since this way (with `Integer`) seems to be working for all the situations (field either indexed or not indexed) I'll change my code to always use it:

  ```
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Contrato" LookupId="True"/>
        <Value Type="Integer">667</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
   </Query>
  ```